# Hierarchical Virtualization Constraints

Tags: wpf, treeview

I came across these 3 options while I was populating a TreeView in WPF

1. HierarchicalVirutalizationConstraints[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.hierarchicalvirtualizationconstraints(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. HierarchicalVirtualizationHeaderDesiredSizes[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.hierarchicalvirtualizationheaderdesiredsizes.pixelsize(v=vs.110).aspx)
3. HierarchicalVirtualizationItemDesiredSizes[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.hierarchicalvirtualizationitemdesiredsizes(v=vs.110).aspx)

The MSDN articles are very opaque and I cannot find it in my [reference book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672336979)
 Google does not have any links suggesting example usage. I would like to know how these structs are used in WPF. I figure SO is a good place to start after my research. Any help/suggestions?

Comment: I'm unaware if there is any good sample or explanation, provided by third-party, but I'd recommend you to look how Microsoft itself uses them in WPF. For that you can visit referencesource.microsoft.com and look how those type are implemented and where and how they are used inside WPF.

Comment: I actually did check that source out, but unfortunately it only lists the code used to build these structs and its properties. There is no use case mentioned like in some of the MSDN reference pages. Or am I looking at it the wrong way? Thanks

Comment: If you click on type/member usage - you will be navigated to it's definition. If you click on definition - you'll see a list of usages on the left side of a page